# Cannot upgrade to 21.2 because decomissioned node is unavailble - Cluster Version Error

Tags: upgrade, cockroachdb

When I try to SET CLUSTER SETTING to 21.1, an error message says “ERROR: n2 required, but unavailable” (n2 is reference to a node, but n2 doesn’t exist, because I can see it as decommissioned 2 years ago).

Answer (score 0):

Try decomissioning n2 again. The node's state is currently indeterminate (pre 21.1 versions didn’t know about this “final” decommissioned state). Decomissioning the node  once more from a new binary node will let you mark it as decommissioned for good, and let the upgrade proceed. This unclear error message will get fixed when this [issue](https://github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/issues/70084) closes.